# How do add a condition to check if created node is language source (in a multilingual site)?

Tags: rules, i18n-l10n

I need to fire a rule action when a node is created and this node is the original source in a multilingual site. This means that this node is not the translation of other node.

How do add a condition to check if the created node the original source in a multilingual site?

Comment: I think you can check after the node creation if the node has a $node->tnid?

Comment: I solved with a condition based in your comment. Do you mind to move your comment as an answer to accept it? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your created node if it has a $node->tnid. The tnid (translation id) would be not null if its a translation from another node.

Comment: What I've done: I created a condition to check the value of the nid of the source node, then if this value was empty I know it is not a translation node. It works.

Comment: Hi chefnelone, could you please be more specific about your solution? or maybe export here your rule? how nid could be empty if node is already created?, please help, thanks.